# I am trying to make a coca appescript app that displays graphs. How do i do it?

Tags: xcode, macos, graph, applescript

I can't work out how to make applescript in xcode 3.2 display graphs, or links to graphs. How do i do it????

Tom

Comment: Your applescript is not working or you are out of idea to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot of things available in cocoa frameworks, bezier path etc.

Don not use applescript, in sandboxed app, it will not work.